# Question about the Legendre's symbol: $\left(\frac{p-1}{5}\right) \overset?= \left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

I was reading about Legendres symbol (number theory) and encountered the following equality:

[image]

I don't understand how they got
$$\left(\frac 3p \right) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{3-1}{2}}\left(\frac{p-1}{3}\right) \tag{underlined with red}$$
I thought $p-1$ in RHS should have been $p$ instead but saw the same thing in the other part of the section:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

I tried to show that the last image illustrates the true identity as follows:
$$\left(\frac{p-1}{5}\right) = \left(\frac{2\cdot\frac{p-1}{2}}{5}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)\left(\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{5}\right) =\left(\frac{\frac{p-1}{2}}{5}\right) $$

But I can't show that the last expression is equal to $(5/p)$.

Is there anything I missed while learning the theory behind this symbol?

Comment: $(5/11)$ is non-zero in contrary to $((11-1)/5)$ so yes it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that should have been $p$ instead of $p-1$. It is certainly false in general that
$$\left( \frac 3p\right) = (-1)^{(p-1)(3-1)/4} \left( \frac {p-1}3\right) \,.$$
For example, when $p = 5$ the LHS is $-1$ and the RHS is $1 \cdot 1$.

Maybe the author got caught up in writing all the $p-1$'s in the exponents.

Comment: Thank you for your response! If it is not true in general could one characterize all such $p$'s? Or is there no such prime numbers?

Comment: Characterizing those $p$'s seems very very difficult, if not impossible. Because the question combines multiplicative and additive information: the multiplicative information about $p-1$ being a square mod $3$ or not and $p$ being a prime, and the additive information that $(p-1) + 1 = p$. Compare with the twin prime conjecture: are there infinitely many primes $p, q$ for which $p = q+2$? That's multiplicative+additive too.

Comment: Sorry, no. In general, yes, multiplicative+additive problems are very hard, but some are not, like here: we just want to know when $\left(\frac p3 \right) = \left(\frac{p-1}3 \right)$. The answer is simply, never, because $p$ and $p-1$ would need to have the same congruence class mod $3$.

Comment: To your last comment: Actually, if I am not mistaken we need $\left(\frac 3p\right) = \left(\frac{p-1}{3}\right)$.